# How to assign value to a column of data table by function call using grouping

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create a column called val in the datatable dt by processing the group that is passed to the function calcVal

```
calcVal<-function(x) {
 # return a column of values by processing all the columns of the data table corresponding to that group
}

dt[,val:=calcVal,by=group_id]
```

How can I pass that group to the function calcVal?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but maybe `dt[, val := calcVal(.SD), by = group_id]`? Or `dt[, lapply(.SD, calcVal), by = group_id]`? But it's hard to tell as your question is very vogue without a reproducible example and desired output

Comment: What is .SD? I want to pass all the columns without explicity writing their names

Comment: `.SD` is an additional `data.table` object containing all the columns of `dt` for that group. You should read the documentaitons

Answer (score 0):

As @David pointed out, if you read `?data.table` there are special variables you can use when you perform a `by=` operation in data.table. So for example

```
library(data.table)
calcVal<-function(SD, BY) {
    paste(BY,SD$x-1, round(SD$y*5,3), sep="_")
}

dt<-data.table(x=1:10, y=runif(10), group_id=rep(letters[1:2], each=5))
dt[,val:=calcVal(.SD, .BY),by=group_id]

#      x          y group_id       val
#  1:  1 0.81431099        a a_0_4.072
#  2:  2 0.81022670        a a_1_4.051
#  3:  3 0.79922535        a a_2_3.996
#  4:  4 0.62207166        a  a_3_3.11
#  5:  5 0.46298899        a a_4_2.315
#  6:  6 0.65807961        b  b_5_3.29
#  7:  7 0.06256007        b b_6_0.313
#  8:  8 0.30950615        b b_7_1.548
#  9:  9 0.94511284        b b_8_4.726
# 10: 10 0.70209066        b  b_9_3.51
```

Of course this is a silly example. It would have helped had you provided your own example data and been clear about what you were trying to accomplish in your helper functions. If you didn't want to pass all the variables, you could have just specified which ones you wanted.

```
calcVal<-function(x, g) {
    paste(g,x, sep="_")
}

dt<-data.table(x=1:10, y=runif(10), group_id=rep(letters[1:2], each=5))
dt[,val:=calcVal(x, group_id),by=group_id]
```